# How can I make 1 button click fill out 2 different text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help making this program fill out 2 different text boxes. It works if I only use it to fill out 1 text box using a First name. But when I try and add another text box to generate a random Last name it just seems to do fail.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random r = new Random();
        int currentLine = 1;
        string pick = null;
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\First Names.txt"))
        {
            if (r.Next(currentLine) == 0)
            {
                pick = line;
            }
            ++currentLine;
            textBox1.Text = pick;
        }
            Random n = new Random();
            int currentLine1 = 1;
            string pick1 = null;
            foreach (string line1 in File.ReadLines("C:\\Last Names.txt"))
            {
                if (n.Next(currentLine1) == 0)
                {
                    pick1 = line1;
                }
                ++currentLine1;                   
                textBox2.Text = pick1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use debugger to trace? the fact that u r using C# means u r using visual studio? its really not hard to trace ur code using break points.

Comment: when you say "But when I try and add another text box to generate a random Last name" are you trying to generate the control on the fly or does it already exist?

Comment: your code is working for me.. as Mox said try to put a breakpoint and check if you are getting data from `Last Names.txt` file.

Comment: Your Code is working fine there is no problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the path for the file is appropriate.
2. You need not create two objects for the same class and access them differently.One object is enough.
   3.Check whether data is there in the file or not.`Random r = new Random();

   ```
   int currentLine = 1;
   string pick = null;
   foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\First Names.txt"))
   {
       if (r.Next(currentLine) == 0)
       {
           pick = line;
       }
       ++currentLine;
       textBox1.Text = pick;
   }       
   currentLine=0;pick=0;
   foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Last Names.txt"))
       {
           if (r.Next(currentLine) == 0)
           {
               pick = line;
           }
           ++currentLine;

           textBox2.Text = pick;
       }
   }`
   ```

If the first iteration gets the value, then the second must also get. Else there is some problem with Text file or the 'textBox2' is not the correct ID you are looking for.

Comment: first check whether if you are getting any data from the file.. you can use an alert box for that.. also try to assign it to some other label if it works then this should work.. :)